# How can I get collection result "column headers" or "column names" in Magento 1.9x?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-1, collection

How can I get collection result "column headers" or "column names" from query?

Suppose I have `$data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();` and I have some joins with other tables

I can get the data by running foreach on `$data` giving me the actual output data.

**question**: but how can I get the "header name" (or "column name") as I would see it when I run the same query in MySQL

[image]

Comment: When referring to `$data` you mean you need to get all array keys within that?

Comment: I am looking to get the column name (the data header value) not the data within the data matrix itself

Answer (score 2):

For a simple query like `SELECT * FROM 'sales_flat_order'`

```
$res    = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read   = $res->getConnection('core_read');
$table  = $res->getTableName('sales/order');
$header = array_keys($read->describeTable($table));
```

To get all product attributes from  `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` just use keys from `$item->getData()`.

Comment: It is a collection with joins etc

Comment: @snh_nl whats wrong with `getData()`?

Comment: So on first for each iteration grab keys?

Comment: @snh_nl Yep. I'd do so.

Answer (score 0):

To get the collection's columns, consider the following.

```
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection() ?>
<?php $columns    = $this->getColumns(); ?>
```